# ID Ends With in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I am working in a Javascript library that brings in jQuery for one thing: an "ends with" selector.  It looks like this:

```
$('[id$=foo]')
```

It will find the elements in which the `id` ends with "foo".

I am looking to do this without jQuery (straight JavaScript).  How might you go about this?  I'd also like it to be as efficient as reasonably possible.

Comment: Can you provide more information ? What kind of dom elements are you targeting ? Is it just DIVs and SPANs or anything ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, they are all input tags, but the query above does not specify that.  I am re-working an existing library, so I can't be completely sure.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll`, [not available in all browsers (like IE 5/6/7/8) though](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/core/). It basically works like jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/BBaFa/2/

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("[id$=foo]"));
```

Comment: I need this code to work everywhere, but +1 for the introduction to JS Fiddle.  Very cool!

Comment: Use `[attribute^=value]` for elements whose *attribute* value begins with a specified *value*.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to iterate over all elements on the page and then use string functions to test it. The only optimizations I can think of is changing the starting point - i.e. not `document.body` but some other element where you know your element will be a child of - or you could use `document.getElementsByTagName()` to get an element list if you know the tag name of the elements.

However, your task would be **much** easier if you could use some 3rd-party-javascript, e.g. [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) (4k minified, the same selector engine jQuery uses).

Answer (score 1):

So, using everything that was said, I put together this code.  Assuming my elements are all `input`s, then the following code is probably the best I am going to get?

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
};

function getInputsThatEndWith(text) {

    var result = new Array();
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if(inputs[i].id.endsWith(text))
            result.push(inputs[i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I put it on JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MF29n/1/

Answer (score 1):

@ThiefMaster touched on how you can do the check, but here's the actual code:

```
function idEndsWith(str)
{ 
  if (document.querySelectorAll)
  {
    return document.querySelectorAll('[id$="'+str+'"]');
  }
  else
  {
    var all,
      elements = [],
      i,
      len,
      regex;

    all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    len = all.length;
    regex = new RegExp(str+'$');
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (regex.test(all[i].id))
      {
        elements.push(all[i]);
      }
    }
    return elements;
  }
}
```

This can be enhanced in a number of ways. It currently iterates through the *entire* dom, but would be more efficient if it had a context:

```
function idEndsWith(str, context)
{
  if (!context)
  {
    context = document;
  }
  ...CODE... //replace all occurrences of "document" with "context"
}
```

There is no validation/escaping on the `str` variable in this function, the assumption is that it'll only receive a string of chars.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested changes to [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248703/id-ends-with-in-pure-javascript/5249391#5249391):

```
RegExp.quote = function(str) {
     return str.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}-])/g, "\\$1");
}; // from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/#494122

String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return !!this.match(new RegExp(RegExp.quote(suffix) + '$'));
};

function getInputsThatEndWith(text) {

    var results = [],
        inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
        numInputs = inputs.length,
        input;

    for(var i=0; i < numInputs; i++) {
        var input = inputs[i];
        if(input.id.endsWith(text)) results.push(input);
    }

    return results;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/yJjDV/

Implementing `String.endsWith` using a regex instead of `indexOf()` is mostly a matter of preference, but I figured it was worth including for variety. If you aren't concerned about escaping special characters in the suffix, you can remove the `RegExp.quote()` bit, and just use
`new RegExp(suffix + '$')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type of DOM elements you are targeting,
then get a list of references to them using `getElementsByTagName` , and then iterate over them.

You can use this optimization to fasten the iterations:

- ignore the elements not having id.
- target the nearest known parent of elements you want to seek, lets say your element is inside a div with id='myContainer', then you can get a restricted subset using
  `document.getElementById('myContainer').getElementsByTagName('*')` , and then iterate over them.