# How to get Javascript getElementById base on partial string?

Tags: javascript

I need to get the ID of an element but the value is dynamic with only the end of it is the same always.

Heres a snippet of the code.

```
<TABLE ID="_MIPS-LRSYSCPU">
```

The ID always ends with '-LRSYSCPU' then the _MIPS is dynamic.

How can I get the ID using just JavaScript and not jQuery? thanks

Comment: The code is simply:

Comment: <TABLE ID="_MIPS-LRSYSCPU" >

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/5249009/5621827

Answer (score 4):

Use the selector `[id$="<END OF ID HERE>"]`:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('[id$="-LRSYSCPU"]');
console.log(table);
```

```html
<TABLE ID="_MIPS-LRSYSCPU">
```

Similarly, by using `^` instead of `$`, you can select elements who attributes start with a certain string:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('[id^="_MIPS"]');
console.log(table);
```

```html
<TABLE ID="_MIPS-LRSYSCPU">
```

And `*=` to select elements who attributes *contain* a certain string:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('[id*="LRS"]');
console.log(table);
```

```html
<TABLE ID="_MIPS-LRSYSCPU">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I have seen that I have different ID with this name. What I mean is that I have:

Comment: <A ID=MIPS-LRSYSCPU  CLASS="CALEN" HREF="../DXXXXXXX/LRSTART.DXXXXXXX.HTML#LRSYSCPU" title='Navigation Calendar'>

Comment: thn I have: <TABLE ID="_MIPS-LRSYSCPU">

Comment: how can I take only the id refer to the TABLE ?

Comment: Put the tag name to the left of the `[`: `table[id$="...`

Comment: because writing const table = document.querySelector('[id$="-LRSYSCPU"]'); i took the first ID I find which is the href, and i don't want this, because I need the TABLE ID

Comment: In this way? const table = document.querySelector('table[id$="_MIPS"]');

Comment: That would select tables whose IDs end with `_MIPS`, but you said that the distinguishing factor was ending in `-LRSYSCPU`?

Comment: yes i did a mistake I supposed to say: const table = document.querySelector('[id$="-LRSYSCPU"]');